# react component disappears when using filter to search through array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got an array of students with the ability to add a tag to each student. The tag system works perfect but when I use my search, if the student is filtered out from the search when I return to the original list (delete out of search bar) the tags component disappears. The tags are still within the student object but they won't render again. I assume it's because of my search logic but I can't seem to figure it out.

Search function

```
useEffect(() => {
    const filterStudents = () => {

      if(Object.values(searchQuery).some((term) => !!term)) {
        const keys = Object.keys(searchQuery);
        let newStudentList = students;
        console.log(newStudentList);
        keys.forEach((key) => {
          switch(key) {
            case "name": 
              newStudentList = newStudentList.filter((student) => {
                const name = student.firstName.concat(" ", student.lastName).toLowerCase();
                return name.includes(searchQuery.name);
              });
              break;
            case "tag":
              newStudentList = newStudentList.filter((student) => {
                const tags = student.tags;
                console.log("Tags " + tags + "\nSearch query " + searchQuery.tag);
                if(tags !== undefined) {
                  return tags.includes(searchQuery.tag);
                }
                
                return true;
              })
              break;
            default:
              break;
          }
        })

        return newStudentList;
      }
      else {
        return students;
      }
    }

    setSearchResults(filterStudents());
  }, [students, searchQuery]);
```

Student Component

```
const Student = ({ student, onUpdateStudent }) => {

  const [btnOpen, setBtnOpen] = useState(false);

  const averageGrade = (grades) => {
    let total = 0;
    let count = 0;
    let average;
    
    for(const grade of grades) {
      total += +grade;
      count++;
    }

    average = total / count;
    return Math.round(average * 1000) / 1000;
  };
  
  const studentAverage = averageGrade(student.grades);

  const openScores = (isOpen) => {
    setBtnOpen(isOpen);
  };

  const onAddTag = (tags) => {
    const updatedStudent = { ...student, tags: tags };
    onUpdateStudent(updatedStudent);
  }
  
  const onDeleteTag = (tags) => {
    const updatedStudent = { ...student, tags: tags };
    onUpdateStudent(updatedStudent);
  }
  


  return (
    <div className="student grid">
      <div className="student-image">
        <img className="" src={student.pic} alt="Student" />
      </div>

      <aside className="student-info">
        <div className="flex">
          <p className="fs-700 fw-bold">{ student.firstName } { student.lastName }</p>
          <ScoreButton btnOpen={btnOpen} onClick={openScores} />
        </div>

        <ul>
          <li>
            <p>Email: { student.email }</p>
          </li>

          <li>
            <p>Company: { student.company }</p>
          </li>

          <li>
            <p>Skill: { student.skill }</p>
          </li>

          <li>
            <p>Average: { studentAverage }%</p>
          </li>
        </ul>

        {btnOpen && <StudentGrades student={student} />}

        <Tags onAddTag={onAddTag} onDeleteTag={onDeleteTag} />
      </aside>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Tags and tag component

```
const Tags = ({ onAddTag, onDeleteTag }) => {

  const [tags, setTags] = useState([]);

  const onAdd = (newTag) => {
    const newTags = [...tags, newTag];
    setTags(newTags);
    onAddTag(newTags);
  }

  const onDelete = (tagDelete) => {
    const newTags = tags.filter((tag) => tag !== tagDelete);
    setTags(newTags);
    onDeleteTag(newTags);
  }
  
  

  return (
    <div className="tags">
      <div className="tags-list">
        {tags.length > 0 && tags.map((tag) => (
          <Tag key={tag} tag={tag} onDeleteTag={onDelete} />
        ))}
      </div>

      <AddTag onAddTag={onAdd} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Tags
```

```
const Tag = ({ tag, onDeleteTag }) => {
  return (
    <div className="tag">
      { tag }
      <i className="fas fa-times fa-sm" onClick={() => onDeleteTag(tag)}></i>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Tag
```

It is only the tag component that seems to disappear. I can add another tag no problem but the list of tags that were there won't render again. Hopefully that makes sense, any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I wasn't passing down the tags into the tags component for them to render again. I'm working on solving by either passing student down into tags component or by lifting tags state up into student component.